# It doesnt work to specify CSS class for ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I've read through some of the documentation on Widgets and after looking up a couple of threads on stackoverflow i found a couple of people having the same problem, but their solution does not work for me.

I'm trying to specify the css class for the ModelChoiceField and im only getting the error "**init**() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)".

This is the code i have related to this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField
..
widgets = {'categoryID': ModelChoiceField(queryset="", widget=ModelChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})), 
}
..
```

I read in the two other answers that they were trying to specify the attrs attribute as an attribute to the Field and not the widget, so above im specifying it as an attribute to the widget, but it still doesnt work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you're trying to pass the whole field in the widgets dictionary. As the name implies, you only need to pass the widget itself. Plus, you've set both the field and the widget as a field class. Obviously, the widget needs to actually be a widget, not a field.

```
widgets = {'categoryID': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}
```

Comment: right, so ModelChoiceField is not a widget..i thought that when i changed the widget when specifying options in the widget assignment that the widget would be changed, but when i can use any widget i want and still get a ModelChoiceField then it works nicely.. didnt really see the "Field" in ModelChoice i think. thanks again daniel